# New to batch and having issues with multiple variables and for loops

Tags: variables, batch-file, for-loop

Trying to find out which users have google chrome by searching the appdata folder of each user for the executable and then a series of actions to take if found. On our system some of the user folders are on a persistent disk, D:. I used a for loop for both instances but I'm sure there is a better way.

If I run it from the computer it seems to work but when ran as a start up nothing seems to happen. Wondering if someone could point out issues or inefficiencies, I know there in there.

```
@ECHO OFF

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

FOR /D %%H IN ("D:\Users\*") DO (
    IF EXIST "%%H\appdata\local\google\chrome\application\chrome.exe" (
    DEL /Q "%%H\Desktop\Google Chrome.lnk"
    msiexec /i "[MSI PATH]" /quiet
    ECHO %DATE% %COMPUTERNAME% %%H Replaced >> "ChromeInstalls.txt"
    )
)   

FOR /D %%G IN ("C:\Users\*") DO (
    IF EXIST "%%G\appdata\local\google\chrome\application\chrome.exe" (
    DEL /Q "%%G\Desktop\Google Chrome.lnk"
    msiexec /i "[MSI PATH]" /quiet
    ECHO %DATE% %COMPUTERNAME% %%G Replaced >> "ChromeInstalls.txt"
    )
)

EXIT /b
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There looks to be nothing wrong with your code.  Place a line `echo %%H&pause` after the `IF EXIST` lines and execute your code - check that the existing locations are detected.  If it fails only in a startup script then permissions might be the problem.

Comment: It found what I was looking for. I was told it wasn't a permissions issue but I'l check again because every time I run it manually it works as it should.

Comment: Figured it out. The call path for this script in the actual start up script had small typo. Thank you for assuring me of my sanity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are parsing invalid path to the for body . Try using /r switch to lock on the parent drive  containing the chome file to process all subdirectories inside the specified drive  so that you dont have to use a full path in your set () eg ..

@echo off

```
  For /r d: %%a in (*) do (

  If "%%~nxa"=="Chrome.exe" (

      DEL /Q "%%G\Desktop\Google Chrome.lnk"
      msiexec /i "[MSI PATH]" /quiet
      ECHO %DATE% %COMPUTERNAME% %%G Replaced >> "ChromeInstalls.txt"

       )

  )




  For /r c: %%a in (*) do (

  If "%%~nxa"=="Chrome.exe" (

      DEL /Q "%%G\Desktop\Google Chrome.lnk"
      msiexec /i "[MSI PATH]" /quiet
      ECHO %DATE% %COMPUTERNAME% %%G Replaced >> "ChromeInstalls.txt"

        )

   )
```

Try that out . Hpe this helps .

Comment: Okay. This makes some sense, I was using the wrong for argument. Could you break down what %%~nxa does? So I can understand and use it in the future instead of just copying.

Comment: So I've been playing with this. So far I haven't had any luck, even less than before. I commented everything out but the the FOR and IF lines and after the second "DO" I put ECHO found it, just to see if it's detecting the .exe that I know is there but I'm getting nothing. Perhaps I missed something in your explanation, as stated, I'm fairly new to this.

Comment: If you mean that the code doesn't work correctly, this is due to the `do` statement after the condition `if "%%~nxa"=="Chrome.exe"`; it is not needed in a conditional statement.

Comment: %%~nxa would expand the local variable to its name and extension only doing away with the file path .. read more about expansion to get more details

Comment: I've made some change by doing away with the path after the L switch .. this should work not tested yet ....